# show matching mysql table results only once?

Tags: php, mysql

hi I'm looking for a way to only show a matching set of mysql results only once. can anyone tell me how to do this?

here's an example of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
id  |  profile_id  | viewed_profile_id | date_viewed
1          4                7              00:00:00
2          5                6              00:00:00
1          4                7              00:00:00
```

so if profile_id and viewed_profile_id match then to only show one result for those matching columns rather than twice or three times or however many times it appears in the database?

Comment: you could add a `select distinct clause` to the query to get unique set of values for the same

Comment: only show one result for profile_id,viewed_profile_id ... which one? the largest, the last, the first, the smallest?

Comment: Your data set and explanation is rather confusing. Can you post a few more example rows and also the output you expect?

Comment: IMO it's not clear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, profile_id, viewed_profile_id, date_viewed
FROM myTable
```

This will show only one row for each unique combination of the columns selected.

---

Or, reading into your question *a lot* (since you only want to match `profile_id` and `viewed_profile_id`), if you want to show the latest date viewed for each viewer, you can use `GROUP BY` and select the `MAX` date viewed. I am also assuming there is data in date_viewed and it is sortable:

```
SELECT profile_id, viewed_profile_id, MAX(date_viewed)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY profile_id, viewed_profile_id
```

Comment: the question is not about finding all the rows only once, but it is about finding those rows which match  profile_id and viewed_profile_id values and that too only once.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha I'm not sure why the downvote here. You are making assumptions about the question just as I am.

Comment: I am sorry for the downvote but the answer you gave with the Distinct keyword was not right. The question is clear. Please read the statement "so if profile_id and viewed_profile_id match then to only show one result for those matching columns rather than twice or three times or however many times it appears in the database?"

Comment: @SaurabhSinha I humbly disagree but we will have to wait for the OP here.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha, when 3 people answer with 'distinct', regardless true answer, i think the question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT helps to eliminate duplicates.  If a query returns a result that contains duplicate rows, you can remove duplicates to produce a result set in which every row is unique. To do this, include the keyword DISTINCT after SELECT and before the output column list

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(` profile_id`),`viewed_profile_id`,`id`,`date_viewed` FROM `tableName` GROUP BY `viewed_profile_id`
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE profile_id = '$PROFILEIDVALUE' AND viewed_profile_id = '$VIEWEDIDVALUE' LIMIT 0, 1"
```

Depending upon the ORDER you want use can use ORDER BY id DESC/ASC

I hope this would be useful

Comment: please explain why is the answer down-voted. When anybody down votes an answer a comment should be posted accordingly.

Comment: FWIW, you do realize this is 1)potentially quite dangerous and 2)comparing most-likely-numeric column data with strings, as well as 3)arbitrarily selecting some row without rhyme or reason. (This is of course completely aside from the interpretation of the question, which only the OP will know what they meant. I understand how this interpretation can also be valid.)

Comment: @Ic. I dont know how could the simple statement (so if profile_id and viewed_profile_id match then to only show one result for those matching columns rather than twice or three times or however many times it appears in the database?) be mis-interpreted. Anyways you are far more experienced than me of-course.

Comment: Because the column data can match among rows. That is, the OP has two "matching" rows in their example data. I surely can't be alone in this interpretation as there are two other very similar answers to mine. But you may very well be correct here; as I say only the OP will know.

Comment: @Ic. I Agree with you totally. Its just I found it clear for the answer I gave. anyways I would upvote you for the same.